# Model an ellipsoidal sphere rolling on another ellipsoidal sphere in Matlab

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, matlab, math-software

How to model the rolling between ellipsoidal spheres, i.e., an ellipsoidal sphere rolls in an arbitrary direction on the surface of another sphere with a different radius?
Thank you !

Comment: The software just solves the model.  The modeling is done by the mind first.   And that is a math problem, not a software problem (this part is independent of what software you are using).  I'm adding some relevant tags.

Comment: Also: 1. You need to state your question with more details.  Is this rolling with or without slipping? Is the rolling spheroid acting under gravity? Unlike in the case of a perfect sphere, that will affect the trajectory it wants to take. Is it rolling inside or outside the other spheroid.  Finally, and this is important, please show us what your work and where you are stuck.